# Limit number of mongodb objects appearing per page and then paginate

Tags: mongodb, express, pagination

I'm working on a blog app using express and Mongodb. I have a show page with the following code:

```
<% include ./partials/header %>

<div class = "container">
<div class = "jumbotron show">
    <h2><%= blog.title%></h2>
</div>
<div class="showWidth">
    <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-md-12 showDate"><%= blog.created.toDateString()%>  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <img class = "center-block showImage" src= "<%= blog.image%>">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class ="col-md-12 showText"><%- blog.body%></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <img class = "center-block showImage" src= "<%= blog.imageTwo%>">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class ="col-md-12 showText"><%- blog.bodyTwo%></div>
    </div>

<% if(currentUser && currentUser.id === "58c9bb76854068369807957c"){ %>
    <a href="/blogs/<%=blog._id%>/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Edit blog</a>
<div>
<form id="delete" action ="/blogs/<%=blog._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete blog</button>
</form>
<% } %>

        <hr class = "style-two">

<!--================== COMMENTS DISPLAY SECTION ====================================================================-->
<div id="comments">
    <% blog.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
    <div class="comment-container">
        <div class="jumbotron comment">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <img class="comment-ico" src = "    <%=comment.author.image%>">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h4><%=comment.author.username%></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 date">
                     <%= moment(comment.created).fromNow()%>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div><p><%=comment.text%></p></div>

<!--=================EDIT COMMENT FORM =========================================================================-->
       <form id="edit-comment-form" action = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=PUT" method = "POST" id="newComment">
            <textarea class = "form-control" rows="4" name = "comment[text]"><%=comment.text%></textarea>
            <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
        </form>

    <!--    ==================================================================================================================-->



        <% if(currentUser && currentUser.username == comment.author.username) { %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 choice">
                    <a class="edit">Edit</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <form id = "delete-form" action = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=DELETE" method = "POST">
                    <input type = "submit" class = "button-delete" value = "Delete"></form>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <hr class = "style-three">
    </div>
    <% }) %>
</div>
</div>


 <% if(currentUser){ %>
 <div class = "container form">
   <form action = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments" method = "POST" id="newComment">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img class="newComment-ico" src = "<%=currentUser.image%>">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label for="comment">Add comment</label>
        </div>
    </div>
        <textarea class = "form-control" rows="4" placeholder = "Type comment here..." name = "comment[text]"></textarea>
        <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<% } %>

<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

I need to display just the first, say, 5 articles on this page and then pass the next 5 onto an identical second page etc, obviously adding some pagination along the way. How do I do this? I've been looking around and can't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the ODM that you used. But with mongo shell. Your problem can be solve with `$limit` and `$skip` operator of mongo.

Page 1:
`ArticlesModel.find().limit(5)`

Page 2:
`ArticlesModel.find().skip(5).limit(5)`